# How to pull out source code from TFS for a word document on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I've a dev design word document which resides on a SharePoint server. I want that document to pull out few class design diagrams from source code residing on a team foundation server(TFS).
How to do this? The intent is to avoid duplication and have dev design in sync with the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about this? As far as I can tell this has actually nothing to do with SharePoint.

You're looking at Office (Word) automation or a 'macro' or similar that will parse the source code and update the doc. This surely has to be a *massive* project, have you searched for anything out there that will help?